# SafeAreaView cover top header with ImageBackground component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I would like to be able to use the `ImageBackground` component from `react-native` and render an image full screen including the SafeArea top and bottom zone.

[image]

As you can see my background image starts under status bar and does not cover it. I would like to force my background image to cover the status bar also.

I'm using `react-navigation (v5)` and its `SafeAreaView` component.

```
import { SafeAreaProvider, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';


export const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <Navigation/>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
};


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator headerMode={null}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export const LoginScreen = (props: any) => (
  <ImageBackground
    source={resolver.images.login.home1}
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    resizeMode={'cover'}
  >
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View>
        <Text>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  </ImageBackground>
);
```

I don't know how I can make my background image cover also the top status bar to make a full screen image. Some help would be really appreciated I don't see where is my mistake ...